# Service Discovery and Service Repository for AWS Serverless Synchronous calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, aws-lambda, serverless, service-discovery

I'm trying to build a collection of services that implement a simple search functionality. I have services A, B, C and D. A acts as a facade and an aggregator for B, C and D.

So a client would call A to search for something. A would then call B, C and D and aggregate the data from them once it has all of it and then returns the response in a synchronous mode.

I've started to implement the services using AWS Lambda and Api Gateway. Currently A has an environment variable of B's name and I use that to call B inside of A. I would like for A to discover B at runtime since maybe in the future we would add other services as E or F or maybe remove some services and I don't want to modify the code of A.

I've read [here](https://read.acloud.guru/service-discovery-as-a-service-the-missing-serverless-lynchpin-541d001466f4) and [here](https://medium.com/@PaulDJohnston/event-routers-the-missing-serverless-service-9ed51b14f25) about the functionality some people would like to have in the Amazon ecosystem. I've also read the discovery part of what Martin Fowler suggests [here](https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html).

So from what I understand for asynchronous calls the best way should be using SNS and have publishers/subscribers for example. For synchronous calls some people suggest using Api Gateway. I don't really like having an Api Gateway in front of every lambda function (B, C and D). Another problem is how to implement the service registry. I would like to some flexibility in adding and removing the services A uses.

Currently what I'm thinking is to store the services that must be used as a parameter in System Manager Parameter Store for each environment. Then have A query the store and for each function name call it.

**Is it ok to do this that is use the System Manager Parameter Store as a service registry? If not can you point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Cloud Map](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/) should help you implement service discovery for AWS services.